# Regular Expression to replace all non alphanumeric characters except / to empty("") character

Tags: java

I want a regular expression to replace all non alphanumeric characters except '/' with ""(empty character).

This is what I did:

```
LibString.replaceAll(token, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

And the function implementation in LibString is:

```
public static String replaceAll(String source, String regex, String replacement) 
    {
        Pattern pattern = new Pattern(regex, 0);
        Replacer replacer = pattern.replacer(replacement);

        String result = replacer.replace(source);
        return result;
    }
```

The String I gave is :

> 'France vs Tonga'. French International Rugby Blitz H/L 2013.
>   Highlights of the French international Rugby match.

Expected result:

A list of words:

France
vs
Tonga
French
International
H/L
.. etc

Actual Result is:

'France
[empty]
Tonga'.
.French
[empty]

Please advice.

**PLEASE NOTE: I am working on a system which has JVM 1.2 so cant use any of the util.regex or String Replace all kind of methods.

I have imported jregex.jar to my project to utilize the usage of regular expressions.**

Comment: Where exactly do you expect a `HashSet` in your code snippet?

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue.

Comment: There is `replaceAll` method in `String` class already: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: I would say forget about the hashset, it is just a means of storing my split words from the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9//]` insted of `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` to escape `/`

```
 LibString.replaceAll(token, "[^a-zA-Z0-9//]", "");
```